# Two (or more) 'connected' IR sensors?

Tags: arduino, sensor, stm32, infrared

I would like to use two (or more) 1838 IR sensors, to be able to read a (TV?) remote control for controlling my project.

The reason I want two or more is that I want to be able to point at the device from multiple directions.

I checked on some websites and it seems it is quite hard (on an Arduino) to use more than one of them. I'm not sure if I will make it on an Arduino or STM32 yet. But I wonder if there is some circuit to 'combine' them together, so I can use only one pin (not for saving a pin, but not having to check multiple sensors)... is there such a circuit and how would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modules almost always have open collector type output, so the outputs can just be wired together.

Comment: Thanks for this info; good to know.

Comment: It should be possible to create the "wired OR" with these sensors.  The [datasheet](http://eeshop.unl.edu/pdf/VS1838-Infrared-Receiver-datasheet.pdf) shows active-low open collector output (see section 4).